# Freezing table inside ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, fixed-header-tables

I have a table and I want to fix the header...

so fare I've done the following, based on the example in [***THIS***](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html#) link:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="function1">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
                        <table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" class="scrollTable"
                                    style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px;
                                    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;font-weight:bold;">
                            <thead class="fixedHeader">
                                <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                                    <th style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">No.</th>
                                    <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" CssClass="chkBoxPosition" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxHeader_All" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                    </th>    
                                    <th style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Title (Number)</th>
                                    <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="scrollContent"><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="hl" Text='<%#Eval("No")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="hl2" Text='<%#Eval("Title") + " (" + Eval("No") + ")"%>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                                <a href="#"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3"><%#Eval("Status")%></asp:Label></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="hl" Text='<%#Eval("No")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="hl2" Text='<%#Eval("Title") + " (" + Eval("No") + ")"%>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                                <a href="#"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3"><%#Eval("Status")%></asp:Label></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

But its not working...

So what could be wrong in this?

I hope you modify the code in a way makes it working...

THE CSS FILE:

```
/* define height and width of scrollable area. Add 16px to width for scrollbar          */
div.tableContainer {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #963;
    height: 285px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 756px
}

/* Reset overflow value to hidden for all non-IE browsers. */
html>body div.tableContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 756px
}

/* define width of table. IE browsers only                 */
div.tableContainer table {
    float: left;
    width: 740px
}

/* define width of table. Add 16px to width for scrollbar.           */
/* All other non-IE browsers.                                        */
html>body div.tableContainer table {
    width: 756px
}

/* set table header to a fixed position. WinIE 6.x only                                       */
/* In WinIE 6.x, any element with a position property set to relative and is a child of       */
/* an element that has an overflow property set, the relative value translates into fixed.    */
/* Ex: parent element DIV with a class of tableContainer has an overflow property set to auto */
thead.fixedHeader tr {
    position: relative
}

/* set THEAD element to have block level attributes. All other non-IE browsers            */
/* this enables overflow to work on TBODY element. All other non-IE, non-Mozilla browsers */
html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
    display: block
}

/* make the TH elements pretty */
thead.fixedHeader th {
    background: #C96;
    border-left: 1px solid #EB8;
    border-right: 1px solid #B74;
    border-top: 1px solid #EB8;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    text-align: left
}

/* make the A elements pretty. makes for nice clickable headers                */
thead.fixedHeader a, thead.fixedHeader a:link, thead.fixedHeader a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%
}

/* make the A elements pretty. makes for nice clickable headers                */
/* WARNING: swapping the background on hover may cause problems in WinIE 6.x   */
thead.fixedHeader a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 100%
}

/* define the table content to be scrollable                                              */
/* set TBODY element to have block level attributes. All other non-IE browsers            */
/* this enables overflow to work on TBODY element. All other non-IE, non-Mozilla browsers */
/* induced side effect is that child TDs no longer accept width: auto                     */
html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    height: 262px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%
}

/* make TD elements pretty. Provide alternating classes for striping the table */
/* http://www.alistapart.com/articles/zebratables/                             */
tbody.scrollContent td, tbody.scrollContent tr.normalRow td {
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}

tbody.scrollContent tr.alternateRow td {
    background: #EEE;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}

/* define width of TH elements: 1st, 2nd, and 3rd respectively.          */
/* Add 16px to last TH for scrollbar padding. All other non-IE browsers. */
/* http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors        */
html>body thead.fixedHeader th {
    width: 200px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th {
    width: 240px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th + th {
    width: 316px
}

/* define width of TD elements: 1st, 2nd, and 3rd respectively.          */
/* All other non-IE browsers.                                            */
/* http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors        */
html>body tbody.scrollContent td {
    width: 200px
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td + td {
    width: 240px
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td + td + td {
    width: 300px
}
```

Comment: If you are talking about CSS & design issues then please provide CSS too.

Comment: the css is as the one in the link I provided BUT anyway I updated the question with it...